# Nginx returns 404

Tags: nginx, supervisord, nginx-config, vapor, server-side-swift

I started my project (api-template) run on localhost (pid 8907) with supervisor.

[image]

Here is my project's `supervisor.conf` file:

```
[program:api-template]
command=/home/rezuan/api-template/.build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/Run serve --env production
directory=/home/rezuan/api-template/
user=rezuan
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)-stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)-stderr.log
```

Here is my nginx `sites-avilable/default` file:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        try_files $uri @proxy;

        location @proxy {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_pass_header Server;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass_header Server;
        }

}
```

Nginx is successfully run, but doesn't "redirect" to my localhost project and returns 404 error. When I run a project without nginx it works successfully.

[[image][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Vvy.png)
[[image][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTNpH.png)

Comment: That is the default `index.html` file. Your `try_files` statement looks for that file before branching to `@proxy`. You could try `try_files nonexistent @proxy;` or just rename `location @proxy` to `location /`.

Comment: Now I get 502 error
When I try [sudo service nginx status] I get Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server

Comment: Have you checked the error log?

Comment: how to do it? sorry, i'm new in nginx

Comment: when i do `sudo service nginx status`  I get `Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument`